# Disqus Comment for one role type

Tags: users, comments

I have installed Disqus on localhost and want users of a particular role type only to be able to comment. Basically, there are free and premium users but I wish to allow only the premium users to be able to comment using Disqus.
The comments should be visible to every role type but the ability to comment should be given to only the premium users and the administrator.
It would be great if someone could help me out with this !

Answer (score 0):

in admin/config/services/disqus set the location to block

then in admin/structure/block put the "Disqus comment" block below the "Main page content"

Now, edit the Disqus comment block, scroll all the way down, under Visibility Settings, click on roles and check mark premium and administrator.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, you can't remove the comment box. Disqus used to offer a way to do it, but now they don't.

The only workaround, would be to create a block that is displayed for anonymous users and non premium authenticated users only.

Then inside that block put css to hide the comment box behind/underneath the article body.

For Example:

```
<style>
 #disqus_thread { z-index: 1; position: relative; top: -180px;}
 .article-body { z-index: 2; position: relative; background: white;}
</style>
```

Unfortunately, with this tactic you would lose the comment count and the sort option. Although, you could display the comment count using the views module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I guess I wasn't clear enough with my question - The comments should be visible to all but the ability to comment should be limited to only the premium users and the administrator. I will edit my question with this detail.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me ! I tried different options but also realized that by doing so I will also have to remove the reply button, because the free users would still get a chance to reply.

Comment: oh dang, forgot about the reply button lol. Using the default Drupal comments is the only way to achieve this.